# Highlighting a eBook on one Mac not showing up in another Mac?

Tags: books

I highlighted one of my eBooks purchased on the Apple Books store on my work Macbook Pro, and then waited and closed the app.  Rebooted the computer, opened the app and closed the app.  By now the highlightings should have been sync'ed.  My iCloud is only half used (50%).

But when I opened up that book on another Mac, none of the highlightings were there.  One Mac was running Catalina and one was running Mojave by the way.

Does that mean I can highlight the whole book and in the future, it is likely that all my highlightings can just vanish like vapor?

Comment: Have you set up sync bookmarks, highlights etc in books.app preferences ?

Comment: Clearly the changes haven't synced to iCloud. What needs to be debugged is what has prevented that from happening.

Comment: OK, I signed in both Books app on the Mac, but one Mac doesn't have iCloud enabled in the Mac's Settings... and the "Sync" of Books is greyed out as well...  so it won't automatically use iCloud even when both apps have logged in and it won't warn you